# Remove specific string in specific situation

Tags: vb.net

I have formula string which for instance can look like that:

```
dim myvalue = "somevariable1 + anothervalue * thirdvalue"
```

there is specific variable called : `extravariable`

if this variable `extravariable = 0` i would like to remove it from `myvalue`. Note that it could be anywhere: on start/at the end or somewhere in the middle. besides `operator/operators` associated to it should also be removed so at the end my `formula` stasys correcty. Some examples could be:

```
dim myvalue = "extravariable * somevariable1 + anothervalue * thirdvalue"
dim myvalue = "somevariable1 + anothervalue * thirdvalue+extravariable"
dim myvalue = "somevariable1 + (extravariable * anothervalue) * thirdvalue"
```

so after removing it it looks like that:

```
dim myvalue = "somevariable1 + anothervalue * thirdvalue"
dim myvalue = "somevariable1 + anothervalue * thirdvalue"
dim myvalue = "somevariable1 + (anothervalue) * thirdvalue"
```

Those were just examples to catch what i mean.

The only operators which can appear inside formula are: `() - + * / Pow(x,y)`

How can i remove it then safely?

Comment: This kind of example may be available ? 
dim myvalue = "somevariable1  + value / extravariable * anothervalue"

Comment: Seems like this is going to require judicious use of `String.IndexOf` to figure out where in the string the substring is located, so that you know whether to look before or after it for the operator.  If it might end up in the middle, you also need to think about whether you care about whether the pre or post operator is retained.

Comment: This is a bit tricky, as you also will have to remove an operator by considering the operator precedence. E.g. in `a * extra + b` we must remove the op before `extra`. In `a + extra * b` the op after must be removed. I don't know if you can do it with simple string or regex operations. Probably you will have to make a little syntax parser.

Comment: @AliFidanli the only available operators which can appear in formulas are: () - + * / Pow(x,y)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes We know what operators can appear in formula - i updated post see there.

Comment: `Pow` is an extra complication. E.g., `Pow(extra, 0)` = 1, but what should `Pow(extra, y)` be? Obviously not `y`. Probably the whole `Pow` will have to be removed. You will need to do some [Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and then work on the resulting [syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).